# Strange results with model scope

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following scope on my model.

```
class ProgrammeInstance  < ActiveRecord::Base
  # more code

  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :order_by_start_date, -> { order(:start_date) }
  scope :future_with_offset, -> { where("start_date >= ?", Date.today - 7.days) }
  scope :upcoming_with_offset, -> { future_with_offset.published.order_by_start_date }

  # more code
end
```

I used the scope to query a list returned from rails

```
programme_instances.upcoming_with_offset
```

This returns an empty result set. However, if I make the call with the contents of the scope instead of the scope itself like so

```
programme_instances.future_with_offset.published.order_by_start_date
```

I get results returned.

There must be something I just don't know about scopes. Can anyone explain why?

Thanks.

Comment: paste your attributes

Comment: What do the contents of your other scopes look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProgrammeInstance  < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :future_with_offset, -> { where(condition) }
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :order_by_start_date, order('start_date')
end
```

You can call it in controller as

```
ProgrammeInstance.future_with_offset.published.order_by_start_date
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense as I have said in the question. What I am asking is why the first way does not work.

Comment: This is not the answer. I have already said - Why can you not nest your scopes like the above case. I thought it was possible?